# Error in JSONObject

Tags: java, json

I am getting compilation error in JSONObject :

> The constructor JSONObject(String) is undefined

```
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("json.json"));
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    String line = br.readLine();
    while (line != null) {
        sb.append(line);
        line = br.readLine();
    }

    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(sb.toString());
```

Although the code is according to JSON documentation only

Comment: Compilation error? add Try-catch Exception :)

Comment: what package are you using?

Comment: import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;

Comment: You should use import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

Answer (score 0):

```
    BufferedReader br;
    try {
        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("json.json"));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = br.readLine();
        while (line != null) {
            sb.append(line);
            line = br.readLine();
        }
        JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(sb.toString());
        System.out.println(jsonObj);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

You should handle the exception,in case of file not found.
I think this works for you.